# This backup cannot be restored using WITH STANDBY because a database upgrade is needed. Reissue the RESTORE without WITH STANDBY

Tags: sql-server, database-backups, database-restore

We have Server1 on which an automatic backup of DB1 runs every night:

- On the weekend - a Full backup
- On the other nights - a Diff backup

The database is restored on Server2 using "With Standby" option,
and thus the current Diff is restored every night on Server2,
and we get there a Read Only replica (updated to last night).
On the weekends, the Full backup is restored.

Server2 was upgraded to SQL Server 2016 while Server1 remained SQL Server 2012, and due to that, we get the above-mentioned error message.

The solution according to Google is to use the `NoRecovery` option.
The problem is that using `NoRecovery` will leave us an unreadable replica on the weekend (because the recovery hasn't been finished), on the first day of the week we will maybe get an updated replica, but in the following days, we will not be able to restore the current Diff backups.

Is there any solution to this problem, that will let us have an updated restore from 2012 to 2016?

Comment: Did you try restoring without the `WITH STANDBY` option? The problem with restoring an older backup image on a newer database engine is that in some cases (and apparently in yours) you *will* need to upgrade the database file structure to fit the new engine. If that is not possible and still keeping `WITH STANDBY` you have three options, ditch `WITH STANDBY`, upgrade your primary server as well, or set up a new secondary server with the same version as the primary server.

Comment: I don't see any issue,when you restore a database of lower version into a higher version,the total explanation you gave tells nothing about restoring it on lower version.Even if you use mirroring,i don't see any issue(you can't failback though)

Answer (score 0):

Lasse V. Karlsen is correct: there is no way to do it,
and we should either upgrade the instance where the database is restored,
or create a new instance on the same machine with an adequate version, use it to restore, and access it from the existing instance.
Avoid using "With StandBy" is not an option.
We solved by creating a new instance.
Thanks.